# Android Studio importing a project from eclipse to Android studio

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, gradle

My laptop crashed couple months back and I kinda lost touch with software development, just got a new PC recently and wanted to start installing my eclipse and I found out new versions of eclipse no longer support android, so here I am struggling with Android Studio. Please note I have never been a fan of Android Studio. I tried importing my former eclipse project which was bug free into the android studio and it give me this error

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong:
>     Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
>     Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 8 cannot be smaller than version 9 declared in library [com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0] C:\Users\daviestobialex\Workarea\AndroidStudioProjects\perspectiveio\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.google.android.gms\play-services-basement\8.4.0\AndroidManifest.xml
>     Suggestion: use tools:overrideLibrary="com.google.android.gms" to force usage
> - Try:
>     Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

with this i determined android studio was saying my `mindSDK` is to low for the version of libabry i was using but bear in mind it worked with eclipse and with little research i came about this solution of using `<uses-sdk  tools:overrideLibrary="com.google.android.gms"/>` but then it doesn't work and each time i rebuild i it then asks me to use `<uses-sdk  tools:overrideLibrary="com.google.android.gms.gcm"/>` and when i try this `<uses-sdk  tools:overrideLibrary="com.google.android.gms, com.google.android.gms.gcm"/>` it tells me to add another library and so on and foth, so am stuck. And when I try to create a new Project and just copy and paste my source code, it gives me a whole new set of problems. so thanks in advance. from a rookie with love.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried following the steps listed on the android site

http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/migrate.html